# _TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MessageModel>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I get error _TypeError (type '`List\<dynamic\>`' is not a subtype of type '`List\<MessageModel\>`' in type cast) but if I delete the hive from the disk it works.

Here I init Hive

```dart
  Future initHive() async {
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(MessageEnumAdapter().typeId)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(MessageEnumAdapter());
    }
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(UserModelAdapter().typeId)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(UserModelAdapter());
    }
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(MessageModelAdapter().typeId)) {
      Hive.registerAdapter(MessageModelAdapter());
    }
    if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(ChatModelAdapter().typeId)) {
      // only register if MessageModelAdapter is already registered
      if (Hive.isAdapterRegistered(MessageModelAdapter().typeId)) {
        Hive.registerAdapter(ChatModelAdapter());
      }
    }
    // if the box is not exist, create new box
    if (!Hive.isBoxOpen(hiveChatBox)) {
      hive = await Hive.openBox<ChatModel>(hiveChatBox);
    }

    // return hive;
  }
```

And this is `ChatModelAdapter`

```dart
class ChatModelAdapter extends TypeAdapter<ChatModel> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 0;

  @override
  ChatModel read(BinaryReader reader) {
    return ChatModel(
      id: reader.read() as String,
      chatType: reader.read() as String,
      participants: reader.read() as List<String>,
      createdAt: reader.read() as DateTime,
      numberOfNewMessages: reader.read() as int,
      lastMessage: reader.read() as MessageModel?,
      messages: reader.read() as List<MessageModel>,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, ChatModel obj) {
    writer.write(obj.id);
    writer.write(obj.chatType);
    writer.write(obj.participants);
    writer.write(obj.createdAt);
    writer.write(obj.numberOfNewMessages);
    writer.write(obj.lastMessage);
    writer.write(obj.messages);
  }
}
```

The `ChatModel` is combined with more than one model `MessageModel`. I have another Hive box of user model that is more simple and it works there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this doesn't work:

```
messages: reader.read() as List<MessageModel>,
```

You need to cast every element to a type of MessageModel and add it to your new List of type MessageModel.

You can do it like this:

```
messages: List<MessageModel>.from(reader.read()),
```

Answer (score 1):

The read() method is returning a `List<dynamic>`, but you are trying to cast it directly to `List<MessageModel>`.

You can try:

```
messages: (reader.read() as List).map((m) => m as MessageModel).toList()
```

This might solve the issue.
Link - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html